# XQuery doesnt execute

Tags: xquery, saxon

I have an XQuery problem:

```
{
let $x := $document//AOSCAT_MetricDetail//table[@class="pretty-table"]
          //tr/td[8]/text()
let $sum_of_statements_per_method := sum(
          for $a at $i in $x where $a != 0.0 return $a 
    )
let $count_of_statements_per_method := count(
          for $a at $i in $x where $a != 0.0 return $a 
    )
return
if ($count_of_statements_per_method != 0) then
    return <average_statements_per_method>{ 
       $sum_of_statements_per_method 
       div 
       $count_of_statements_per_method 
    }</average_statements_per_method>   
else
    return <average_statements_per_method> 
       No data available 
    </average_statements_per_method>    
}
```

Executing this XQuery with Saxon9 yields the following Error:

```
Error on line 103 column 39 of transform_2.xq:
  XPST0003: XQuery syntax error in #...verage_statements_per_method>{#:
    expected "else", found ">"
Static error(s) in query
```

But i dont understand why. In the same File a have a very similar XQuery expression and there's no problem at all...

Is anyone able to point me to where my mistake is ?

EDIT:
But why does this work ok, then? :

```
{
let $content_check := $document//AOSCAT_MainReport//div[@class="reportpart"][4]/h2/text()
return
if($content_check="Abstraction analysis") then                                                              
let $abstraction := $document//AOSCAT_MainReport//div[@class="reportpart"][4]/table//tr[2]//td[5]
    return <abstraction_level>{ fn:number(fn:normalize-space($abstraction))*100 }</abstraction_level>
else 
    let $abstraction := 0
    return <abstraction_level>{ $abstraction }</abstraction_level>  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have too many `return`s. Your code:

```
return 
  if (...) then ...
    return ...
  else
    return ...
```

Should be:

```
return 
  if (...) then ...
  else ...
```

The [XQuery spec defines an if-statement](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-conditionals) as:

```
IfExpr  ::=  "if" "(" Expr ")" "then" ExprSingle "else" ExprSingle
```

`ExprSingle` can be a value or another expression. Your second example is the latter case: the `let` following the `then` branch implies it is a `FLWOR`-type expression, and therefore must include a `return`. Simply: using `for` or `let` requires `return`.

For more information on the XQuery grammar, please [see the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#doc-xquery-ExprSingle) or the many resources online that explain it more simply.

Comment: I see... I thought just the single `return` would also be a FLOWR-type expression, since [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_select.asp) it says everything but the `return` is optional, hence every `return` represents a FLOWR-expression. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Your "here" points to w3schools. Not for the first time, w3schools has oversimplified things. Although the "for" and "let" clauses are both optional, you must have at least one "for" or "let" clause. (When we did the 3.0 FLWOR clause some of argued against that rule, but we lost.)